# How to get data from a particular CardView attached RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have used a `CardView` to display some data (data displayed by setting values to `TextView` ).This `CarView` is attached to `RecyclerView`. Data displayed is coming from Database and hence the `CardView` also increases in list depending on no of rows in Database. What I want is to get data from particular Card on `onclick` and I am not sure how to do that. and I also wonder that I have used same card to populate different data and the `TextView` also have the same Id on different Card. How do I achieve this.I want to Take Data `onClick` because i will use that to edit the previous Data by modifying it And i Just need the way to get Data `onClick` of `CardView` rest I can do.
My code is as:-
**MedicationCard:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:elevation="6sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/cardMedview">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:padding="4dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NameSection">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Name:-  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Name of Med"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/nameOfUpmingMed"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/QuntitySection"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NameSection"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Quantity:-  "
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="crocin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:id="@+id/QuantOfMed"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Reffil Amount:-  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/QuantOfMed" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="222"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/ReffilAmt"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expirationSection"
                android:layout_below="@+id/QuntitySection">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Expiration Date:-  "
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="XX/YY/ZZZZ"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/ExpDate"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DaysSection"
                android:layout_below="@+id/expirationSection">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Days:-  "
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"  />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN"
                    android:id="@+id/NoOfDays"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/TimeSection"
                android:layout_below="@+id/DaysSection">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Time:-  "
                android:textColor="#0866C4"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
               />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="08:00 AM"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/timeMorning"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="01:00 PM"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/timeAfternoon"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="08:00 PM"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/timeEvening"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="49dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/InstructionSection"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TimeSection">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Instructions:-  "
                    android:textColor="#0866C4"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:text="Take Medicine before bed and after the food.and he shuld take agood sound sleep and shuld wake up early in morning"
                    android:id="@+id/SpecialInst"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView10" />

            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment which is using RecyclerView to populate data on Card view.
**PrescriptionFragment**

```
    public class PrescriptionFragment extends Fragment {

private Context context;
    private  RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseAdaptor databaseAdaptor;
    public PrescriptionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prescription, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        context=getActivity();
        databaseAdaptor = new DatabaseAdaptor(context);
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();




        return view;
    }

    private void initializeData(){
       databaseAdaptor.getDetailData();
    }
    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(databaseAdaptor.persons);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter:**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {


    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cardView;
        TextView Name,Qunat,refill,expDate,Days,moring,after,evening,inst;

        public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardMedview);
            Name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfUpmingMed);
            Qunat=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.QuantOfMed);
            refill=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ReffilAmt);
            expDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ExpDate);
            Days=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NoOfDays);
            moring=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeMorning);
            after=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeAfternoon);
            evening=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeEvening);
            inst=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.SpecialInst);
        }
    }
    List<Person> persons;
    RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons=persons;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.medication_card, parent, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.Name.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.Qunat.setText(persons.get(i).qunt);
        personViewHolder.refill.setText(persons.get(i).refill);
        personViewHolder.expDate.setText(persons.get(i).date);
        personViewHolder.Days.setText(persons.get(i).days);
        personViewHolder.moring.setText(persons.get(i).morning);
        personViewHolder.after.setText(persons.get(i).after);
        personViewHolder.evening.setText(persons.get(i).evening);
        personViewHolder.inst.setText(persons.get(i).inst);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

**Person Class**

```
class Person{
    String name,qunt,refill,inst,date,days,morning,after,evening;
    Person(String name,String quant,String refill,String date,String days,String morn,String Aft,String evening,String inst){
        this.name=name;
        this.qunt=quant;
        this.refill=refill;
        this.date=date;
        this.days=days;
        this.morning=morn;
        this.after=Aft;
        this.evening=evening;
        this.inst=inst;
    }
}
```

And finally my Database which from which i am populating Data.

```
public List<Person> getDetailData(){
      SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
      String[] columns={DatabaseHelper.medicationId,DatabaseHelper.medicName,DatabaseHelper.medicationQuant,DatabaseHelper.expirationDate,
      DatabaseHelper.RiffilAmount,DatabaseHelper.specialInst,DatabaseHelper.alarmDays,DatabaseHelper.timeMorning,
      DatabaseHelper.timeAfternoon,DatabaseHelper.timeEvening};
     Cursor mcursor= db.query(DatabaseHelper.MEDICATION_DETAILS_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
      persons=new ArrayList<>();
      StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
      while (mcursor.moveToNext()){
         int index1= mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.medicationId);
          int index2=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.medicName);
          int index3=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.medicationQuant);
          int index4=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.expirationDate);
          int index5=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.RiffilAmount);
          int index6=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.specialInst);
          int index7=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.alarmDays);
          int index8=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.timeMorning);
          int index9=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.timeAfternoon);
          int index10=mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.timeEvening);
          int medid=mcursor.getInt(index1);
          String name=mcursor.getString(index2);
          String quant=mcursor.getString(index3);
          String expDate=mcursor.getString(index4);
          String refill=mcursor.getString(index5);
          String specialInst=mcursor.getString(index6);
          String alarmdays=mcursor.getString(index7);
          String timemorning=mcursor.getString(index8);
          String timeafter=mcursor.getString(index9);
          String timeevening= mcursor.getString(index10);
          persons.add(new Person(name,quant,refill,expDate,alarmdays,timemorning,timeafter,timeevening,specialInst));

      }
      mcursor.close();
      db.close();
      return persons;
  }
```

And my O/P is as:
[image]

Comment: Set a click listener to a RecyclerView and get data on the item (position) you click. You can see example here to add [on click listener](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Comment: ok will look into that. why was i downvoted did i asked something wrong??

Comment: I don't know. Sometimes, I don't understand why someone downvoted. Maybe they think you can search for this issue.

Comment: Ok but i did searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `CardView` is attached to`RecyclerView`. To fetch data from any `CardView`, you just have to get position of item, which is fetched from RecyclerView position.
Yo can follow this answer:
[RecyclerView ItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471410/6202040/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to Android development but, found something interesting...

[My screen looks as below...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXNxH.png)

So, I've a RecyclerView and a CardView combination, and each item would have a Toolbar attached with it...

So, if I implement the Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener, along with the definition of your ViewHolder class, it should resolve the issue.

Note:  Even if you don't want to use the Toolbar, then implement View.OnClickListener along with the ViewHolder class and implement the OnClick event and I guess, it would do the trick.

[Here is the rest of my ViewHolder class definition...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEzwr.png)

Hope It Helps!!!

Comment: thanks, I have already developed my app and I have done some thing similar to your suggestion and was able to resolve my problem long back. thanks any way